# MapView testing on UI Testing with Xcode

Tags: xcode, automation, mapkit, xcode-ui-testing

I have a map view in an app I am working on.  There is current location and destination markers.  When I am on the page using UI Testing automation, and I call "po XCUIApplication().debugDescription" the map view is seen but none of the details of the map view (current location, etc).

Is there a way to identify the sub objects within map view (e.g. current location markers, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information to be sure (what kind of object is your map view?) but it sounds like your map view itself is an accessible element.

Accessible elements which are not tableview/collection cells, in XCUITests, cannot also be containers. You should be able to set that property to `false` and the elements within your map should now be accessible, so long as for them the property is set to `true`.